# Swipe-delete messages only for current user

Tags: database, database-design, server-side

thanks for taking time looking at my question.

Ok so I'm working on this iPhone app. I'm responsible for the server side code. Client side is asking for a solution to delete private messages from the app. I have created a HTTP DELETE for them that deletes a specific message. But this request deletes the message from the database and that makes the message disappear for both users and not only the one that have choosen to delete it.

I've been thinking but I can't seem to find the best solution for this. What I need is a solution to only delete the message for the current user.

Should I add some columns in the database that tells which user the private message should be shown for? And when a user deletes the message from the app it only stops showing on that users phone. Or is there a better solution for this?

I need help with some brainstorming. I hope it is an OK question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A physical delete should probably be avoided. The first couple of reasons I can think of:

- how can you do proper testing/audit if the information you're looking for is gone?
- legal issues: do you need some levels of data retention?

You can implement some form of logical delete, for example with an extra relation such as UserMessage( UserID, MessageID, MessageStatus ), where MessageStatus could be "unread", "read", "deleted", "important", "spam", etc. (you can map the status to an arbitrary integer if you prefer). When a user deletes a message, you simply change its status in the UserMessage relation, and from the UI side you hide messages which are marked as "deleted".

Comment: That's a great answer, and actually on the dot how I finally solved it. Thanks!